# Is there a way to edit the WP content database in an admin panel or external page?

Tags: database

I have a lot of content and some of it needs to be updated and edited. I was wondering (hoping) that there is a way to access the database from an external linked source, i.e. Excel, or in a table on a page, admin panel, or...
It would be easier to make mass updates/edits instead of opening each post.
Furthermore, even adding new posts by adding connect to the external document, table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this Tchai. The whole point of a CMS is to make editing your site simple.

If you're determined to do this, I would go to `tools > export` and export the page or post data. This will give you an XML feed with all of the posts data on it. You can then re-import it in the same format. However, be very careful doing this. If you edit the wrong thing, delete the wrong thing, it could invalidate the structure. When you come to re-upload it it could be corrupted and either not upload, or worse, upload corrupting your site's database.

**If you do decide to do this, make sure you have backups in place!**

Comment: Thanks. I have a LOT of posts and need to do a mass edit,. I also have a LOT of additional posts to add and don’t have the time to add them one by one. Was hoping there is something like an admin panel in excel format (or something similar) to add/edit bulk posts...